# WPF UI not updating after incoming WCF message

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have an MVVM app, where my ViewModel `PingerViewModel` processes incoming WCF `Ping()` messages. Processing such a message happens on a thread of `Scheduler.Default`'s thread pool.
Semantically, incoming WCF messages change a bound property `CanPing` and raise the PropertyChanged event for said property.

**But my UI is not updating** until it receives some UI event, e.g. focusing/clicking the window, etc.
**How do I make it update as soon as the event is fired?**

I have tried raising the PropertyChanged event...

- on the Application's Dispatcher,
- using a SynchronizationContext

without any luck.

I also verified that the bound property is indeed set to the proper value, and that there is indeed a listener consuming my PropertyChanged event.

Here's some code ([full code on github](https://github.com/derabbink/DistrExTest)):
part of my view's MainWindow.xaml:
It might be worth noting that the bound `Command` does not actually play a role in producing the incoming WCF message.

```
<Button Content="Ping" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="PingBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Ping" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding CanPing}" 
            Command="{Binding PingCommand}" />
```

part of my views MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = new PingerViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

part of my ViewModel

```
public class PingerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    public PingerViewModel()
    {
        Pinger = new Pinger(true);
        PingCommand = new PingerPingCommand(this);
        //...
    }

    public bool CanPing
    {
        get
        {
            if (Pinger == null) return false;
            return Pinger.CanPing;
        }
    }

    public void Ping()
    {
        _pingClient.Channel.Ping();
        Pinger.CanPing = false;
        OnPropertyChanged("CanPing");
    }

    protected virtual void OnPong(PongEventArgs e)
    {
        Pinger.CanPing = true;
        OnPropertyChanged("CanPing");
    }

    public Pinger Pinger { get; private set; }

    public ICommand PingCommand { get; private set; }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Can you post the ViewModel class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove **IsEnabled="{Binding CanPing}"** from your button.

Binding to the command is enough as the ICommand object contains **CanExecute** and the **CanExecuteChanged** event handler.

I would create a CanExecute boolean inside your Command class, and implement INotifyPropertyChanged also on this class. Something like this:

```
public class PingCommand : ICommand, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _canExecute;

    public bool CanExecute1
    {
        get { return _canExecute; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(_canExecute)) return;
            _canExecute = value;
            CanExecuteChanged.Invoke(null, null);
            OnPropertyChanged("CanExecute1");
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //whatever
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then, on the Ping/Pong methods inside your ViewModel, update this property inside your Command:

```
public void Ping()
{
    _pingClient.Channel.Ping();
    Pinger.CanPing = false;
    PingCommand.CanExecute1 = false;
    OnPropertyChanged("CanPing");
}

protected virtual void OnPong(PongEventArgs e)
{
    Pinger.CanPing = true;
    PingCommand.CanExecute1 = true;
    OnPropertyChanged("CanPing");
}
```

Comment: The core of the problem was that I didn't realize that the `IsEnabled` property will already be taken care of by binding a `Command`. In the end I did not need the `CanExecute1` property, since in my ViewModel I can just call `PingCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

if your CanPing Property and the CanExecute methode for your PingCommand both return TRUE it should work.

sometimes the Delegate/RelayCommand implementation give the possibility to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged() - try this if the statement above is true for both and its not working

btw this is called within the RaiseCanExecuteChanged()

```
 CommandManagerHelper.CallWeakReferenceHandlers(_canExecuteChangedHandlers);
```

Comment: I updated my question. N.B.: the Command bound to the button does not play a role in generating the incoming WCF message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method of the said property to update.
Eg:

```
this.PingCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

Try this, I hope it will solve your problem.